# how to support UTF8 (japanese, arabic, spanish, ...) URL's in PHP

Tags: php, utf-8, internationalization

For a web application, we need to link to some user generated content.
A users types in a title for e.g. a product and we generate an SEO friendly url for that product:

like this

```
title: a nice product

www.user.com/product/a-nice-product

title: أبجد هوز

www.user.com/product/أبجد هوز
```

The problem is that those foreign language url's aren't supported and a browser refuses to open those links. I've seen wordpress setups support that kind of url's so I guess it's possible to do this.

Does anyone know how we should support this in php?

wikipedia handles this just fine: http://ar.wikipedia.org

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "just fine". In my IE8, the URL after the last `/` displays as %D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B5%D9%81%D8%AD%D8%A9_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B1%D8%A6%D9%8A%D8%B3%D9%8A%D8%A9.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although the URL itself only allows US-ASCII characters, you can [use Unicode characters in the URI path](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.5) if you encode them with UTF-8 and then convert them in US-ASCII characters by using the [percent-encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1):

> A system that internally provides identifiers in the form of a different character encoding, such as EBCDIC, will generally perform character translation of textual identifiers to UTF-8 [[STD63](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#ref-STD63)] (or  some other superset of the US-ASCII character encoding) at an  internal interface, thereby providing more meaningful identifiers  than those resulting from simply percent-encoding the original octets.

So you can do something like this (assuming UTF-8):

```
$title = 'أبجد هوز';
$path = '/product/'.rawurlencode($title);
echo $path;  // "/product/%D8%A3%D8%A8%D8%AC%D8%AF%20%D9%87%D9%88%D8%B2"
```

Although the URI path is actually encoded with the percent-encoding, most modern browsers will display the characters this sequence represents in Unicode when UTF-8 is used.

Comment: that sounds interesting, but isn't it better for e.g. /product/españa to make this /product/espana instead of /product/espa%F1a  ?

Comment: I'm make sure you check these URLs for copy-paste-ability and bookmark-ability. In my experience they will often work fine when you serve them to the browser as an anchor tag or as a redirect url, but once the browser has to store and retrieve the URL themselves, all bets are off. Hope you find a solution and good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You're in trouble I'm afraid. The encoding of the URL is at the discretion of the browser. I've encountered the same problem when trying to support URLs with Norwegian special characters and its simply not consistently possible.

You may be able to redirect a browser to the UTF-8 URL, but it might reply to you in ISO. It gets even worse in some cases where browsers (firefox for instance) will mix ISO and UTF-8 formatting in the same url (this happens particularly with get parameters).

My suggestion is simply; Don't do it, use either English (better SEO too!) or spell it phonetically.

Comment: for me that's not a problem, but the clients of my web app are international and will use titles in their own language.

Comment: check out http://ar.wikipedia.org, they are handling this just fine so I must be possible?

Comment: @Jorre they have it in the same ugly urlencoded way. It's browser makes it looks nice. Better transliterate it

Comment: Hi @BjornS, thanks but it's not always possible to spell in language e.g. Thai

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use IDNA encoding on the non-ASCII portion of the URL.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name

Comment: IDNA is only for the actual domain name. The remainder of the URL is encoded using percent-encoding (`urlencode()` in PHP).

Comment: can we use urlencode() for encoding all non ascii characters?

Answer (score 0):

You should do urlencode the Arabic or unicode text

```
urlencode('كلام-عربي')
```

And its very important to add the charset code to the head tag of the page, otherwise the link will not work

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```