# arabic url in codeigniter at internet explorer

Tags: codeigniter, url

I'm using codeigniter 2.1.1
when i run any url like :

```
www.mysite.com/search/عربي
```

$key = "عربي";
it worked with all browsers except internet explorer
and IE say: Undefined variable key

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907995/how-to-support-utf8-japanese-arabic-spanish-urls-in-php

Answer (score 1):

According to the standards ([RFC1738](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1738.html)), URLs can only contain ASCII characters. Non-ASCII characters must be encoded. This is a rare case of IE being more standards compliant than other browsers.

I believe you'll find if you use something like HTTP Watch that the other browsers are encoding them to send to the server anyway, just displaying the Unicode characters in the address bar...

Comment: What's wrong with this answer? The URL you are using is not valid, therefore how browsers choose to handle it cannot be guaranteed.