# parameter encoding are sending to server are different from encoding in server

Tags: php, android, json, unicode, android-volley

it is very difficult to explain for me.
but

i m using volley library to get json from server to my android application.
i m using GET to send my parameters to the server.

..../myServer/webservices/myPhp.php?thistime=19700101120000&city=پارسی

this is a example of uri that i send to the server to get json result

when i copy that link to the chrome or any explorer it works fine.
but when i send that link through android and using volley library, the result of json is nothing!

i think there is a problem with two different encoding character in android and my server

one of my parameters which i send it to the server as you can see in above link is arabic font

would you please help me to find out this problem

Comment: Done any basic debugging, like seeing what your arabic text looks like once it reaches the server? You've provided **NO** server-side code, and just seeing this url is NOT enough to try and figure out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The URLs allow only US-ASCII characters, but I guess you can try to encode your data as utf like below:

```
 $city = 'پارسی';
 $encodedPath = rawurlencode($city);
```

**Reference**  [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3908654/1114506)

Comment: I m using SQL command to fetch some data from database. how can i use rawurlencode when $city is a field of my table for search.  select * from jobs where city = $city