# Decoding arabic string

Tags: url, url-rewriting, arabic, string-decoding

Is there a tool to help me convert/decode such a link https://www.yamsafer.me/%D9%85%D8%B5%D8%B1/%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%82%D8%A7%D9%87%D8%B1%D8%A9/%D9%81%D9%86%D8%A7%D8%AF%D9%82-%D8%B1%D8%AE%D9%8A%D8%B5%D8%A9

to its original arabic wording?

Answer (score 1):

The URL is [percent-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

There are [online tools](http://urldecode.org)  which allow you to decode the string.
In this example it yields [https://www.yamsafer.me/مصر/القاهرة/فنادق-رخيصة](https://www.yamsafer.me/%D9%85%D8%B5%D8%B1/%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%82%D8%A7%D9%87%D8%B1%D8%A9/%D9%81%D9%86%D8%A7%D8%AF%D9%82-%D8%B1%D8%AE%D9%8A%D8%B5%D8%A9)

Happy holidays.

Answer (score 0):

السلام عليكم
Here's [an issue exactly like yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907995/how-to-support-utf8-japanese-arabic-spanish-urls-in-php) have a look on it.

for notice: You're looking for using "UTF8 URL" which includes Arabic.
so if you searched for solution search for this title not what you've mentioned. you'll find lot of topics about it.